# Using UITextField To Get Percentage Through Calculation (Swift 2.0)

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift2, xcode7

I have made an app with two TextFields, a Button and a Label. The result I want is the user puts in a number with no decimals in the first and second TextField, they push the submit button and the label will display the following equation:

> TextField1 / TextField2 * 100

The equation will equal a percentage that may go over 100%

An example is:

TextField1 = 50
TextField2 = 100

TextField1 / TextField2 * 100 = 50

So the label will show 50%

Can someone please provide the Swift code to do this. I have created the action for the button and outlets required.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're showing it ( TextField1 / TextField2 * 100 ) you would end up with 25% as textfield2 would be multiplied by 2 before then being used to divide textfield1. 
(textfield1 * 100) / textfield2 would give the correct result.